# Angular date and time validation MM/DD/YYY HH24MI

Tags: javascript, angular

I am receiving a date and time format as a string like this `'MM/DD/YYY HH24MI'` e.g `10/02/2010 0730`

I am displaying the data in an input field using angular material. I want to validate user's input to match this format to make sure they didn't enter something different. Tried datetime-local but that didn't display it as the format mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.